# RegularExpression matchesInString issue in Swift

Tags: regex, swift, core-text

I am converting a CoreText based app to Swift and I am facing an issue when getting the matches to a regular expression in the text.

This is the sample code

```
let regexOptions = NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators
let regex = NSRegularExpression.regularExpressionWithPattern("(.*?)(<[^>]+>|\\Z)", options: regexOptions, error: nil)
var results: Array<NSTextCheckingResult> = regex.matchesInString(text, options: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(text)))
```

According to the documentation, the `matchesInString` function returns an array of `NSTextCheckingResults`, but the compiler complains stating that "The Expression of type anyObject[] can´t be converted to "`NSMatchingOptions`". Any idea of what might be wrong here?

Comment: You have to cast the results: `regex.matchesInString(text, options: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(text))) as NSTextCheckingResult[]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try assigning to your `results` variable like this:

`var results = regex.matchesInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(text))) as Array<NSTextCheckingResult>`

1. the return type is `Array<AnyObject>[]!`, you can cast here (as in the above example) or later when you check the members of the collection
2. in Swift options take `nil` to represent an empty option set (vs. `0` in Objective-C)

Comment: It turns out that both parts of the answer are required as part of the solution..   The cast as Array<Type> and also the nil for the "0" in option are required. Thx.... and you got my up vote

Comment: For some reason I can only cast to NSTextCheckingResult. That's fine, but how do I get the text value of any of the elements in the results array? The playground just shows the array elements as [NSRegularExpressionCheckingResult,...]

Answer (score 0):

I just sat with a problem related to some regexes and thought I would add a warning to the answer submitted above. My regexes matches seemed to be cut short and it turned out that the range i supplied was incorrect. I generated the range in the way described by @fqdn. It turned out that my strings contained carriage returns (\u{A}) and that these were not counted by the countElements function.
I countered this by calling .unicodeScalars on the string which seems to correctify the lenght.

```
println(countElements("\u{A}\u{A}\u{A}\n\u{D}\n\u{D}\n\u{D}\n\u{D}\n")) //8
println(countElements("\u{A}\u{A}\u{A}\n\u{D}\n\u{D}\n\u{D}\n\u{D}\n".unicodeScalars))  //12
```

Disclaimer: This is quite probably a swift-bug and might get fixed in a later version.